# Facebook JS SDK getLoginStatus inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am adding facebook login to my app, however I encounter issus with one the methods of the SDK - `FB.getLoginStatus`
I have created my own wrapper of the SDK and exposed some of the main methods.

```
/*eslint-disable no-undef*/

class FacebookSDK{
    constructor(options = {}){
        this.options = options;
    }

    isSdkLoaded(){
        return typeof FB !== 'undefined';
    }

    init(){
        window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
            FB.init(this.options);
        }

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const checkIfSdkIsLoaded = () => {
                this.isSdkLoaded() ? resolve() : setTimeout(checkIfSdkIsLoaded, 100);
            }

            checkIfSdkIsLoaded();
        });
    }

    login(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                        resolve(user);
                    });
                } else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    getLoginStatus(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                        resolve(user);
                    });
                } else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

export default FacebookSDK;
```

However when calling `getLoginStatus` my code 'hangs' as the callback is not always called.
Sometimes its called, sometimes it isnt..

I am developing on my local machine under `http://localhost/`

I added the `localhost` to to my "App Domains" Section and have also added `http://localhost/` to Site URL.

Comment: maybe ghostery or some other browser plugin blocking the facebook sdk? also, when do you call getLoginStatus? it should be used in fbAsyncInit only, right after FB.init.

Comment: @luschn that was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which one of my suggestions was the issue, but i am turning this into an answer:

- Maybe ghostery or some other browser plugin is blocking the Facebook SDK
- `FB.getLoginStatus` should be used in `fbAsyncInit` only, right after `FB.init`

Comment: There was a mistake in my flow in the sdk, I wasnt making sure ```FB.init``` was called

Comment: ok, that was actually my number one tip. glad i could help :)